# Getting 400 bad request while trying to use ajax in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get the response from wordpress ajax. but Getting 400 error. Can not find out where is the issue. I have tried many times but could not resolve. jQuery version 3.6. and filter.js file is working perfectly. Please help me.

function.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

function my_script_enqueuer() {
    wp_register_script( "filter_script", get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/filter.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'filter_script', 'filterAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        
    wp_enqueue_script( 'filter_script' );

}


add_action("wp_ajax_publication_filter_function]", "publication_filter_function");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_publication_filter_function", "publication_filter_function");

function publication_filter_function(){
    echo "Response hello";
}
```

filter.js

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    // Get filter value 
    jQuery('.publication-filter').on('change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var filter_value = this.value;
        var nonce_val = jQuery('.filter_ajax_nonce').val();
        
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : filterAjax.ajaxurl,
            data : {
                action: "publication_filter_function", 
                filter_value : filter_value, 
                nonce: nonce_val
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.type == "success") {
                console.log("Hello");
                }
                else {
                console.log("Not hello");
                }
            },
            error : function(error){ console.log(error) }
        });
    })
});
```

response
[image]

Comment: Check network tab for additional details. Also check error logs

Comment: @Justinas from network tab the response is 0 . and nothing get useful from error log. just   json of header data.

Comment: Are you working on a child theme or custom theme?

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani main theme

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @SudiptaDas, Please check my suggested answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_publication_filter_function", "publication_filter_function");
```

I think you have added the `]` bracket by mistake to the ajax hook that's why the ajax call is not working.

Comment: Thank you so much man. You are a savior .

Comment: This answer makes a great case for taking a break sometimes. I'd wager you'd have seen that yourself given a fresh pair of eyes. :)

Comment: You are right . I have been coding since 6 hours long. I need to take break.